# What is the difference between the VSEPR theory and its model?

Tags: vsepr-theory

I know that VSEPR was actually a model proposed by Sidgwick and Powell but then it was developed as a "theory" by Gillespie and Nyholm. Google says that a theory is more detailed and comprehensive as compared to a model. I just want to know what the orignal model stated and what further explanations were there in the theory